# Extracting df from inside function

Tags: python, dataframe, function, scope

I'm trying to access the dataframe when calling the function import_first_excel_csv_file function. The code should run the gui, get the directory and import the xcel in the directory to a dataframe format, then the code below follows further functions to modify that dataframe, however this is the initial dataframe imported thats not working as it says df is undefined

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Directory Input")

dropdown_var = tk.StringVar()
project_value_var = tk.StringVar()

project_type = ["20", "30", "40"]
main_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter the directory path and select project details:")
main_label.pack(pady=10)

directory_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter the directory path:")
directory_label.pack()
directory_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
directory_entry.pack()

dropdown_label = tk.Label(root, text="Select Project Type:")
dropdown_label.pack()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=dropdown_var, values=project_type)
dropdown.pack()

project_value_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter Project Value (MMJ):")
project_value_label.pack()
project_value_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=project_value_var)
project_value_entry.pack()

project_value = project_value_var.get()
project_type = dropdown_var.get()

def submit_directory():
    directory = directory_entry.get()
    root.destroy()
    return directory

submit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: submit_directory())

directory = submit_directory()

def import_first_excel_csv_file():
    directory = directory_entry.get()
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        print(f"Directory '{directory}' does not exist.")
        return

    excel_csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.xlsx")) + glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,
    "*.csv"))

    if not excel_csv_files:
        print("No excel or csv file found in the directory")
        return

    selected_file = excel_csv_files[0]

    try:
        if selected_file.lower().endswith(".xlsx"):
            df = pd.read_excel(selected_file, header=None)
            print(f"Data from '{selected_file}' imported into Dataframe:")
            print(df)
        elif selected_file.lower().endswith(".csv"):
            df = pd.read_csv(selected_file, header=None)
            print(f"Data from '{selected_file}' imported into Dataframe:")
            print(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return df

    print(df.iloc[:, 20])
    print(df.iloc[:, 21])
    print(df.iloc[:, 36])
    print(df.iloc[:, 69])
    print(df.iloc[:, 70])
    return df

import_first_excel_csv_file(df)
df = import_first_excel_csv_file(df)
```

Error is unresolved reference "df" &

```
import_first_excel_csv_file(df)
```

NameError: name 'df' is not defined

It could be the order of my code? Why do I need to define the dataframe df before the try/except loop?

Comment: `import_first_excel_csv_file()` takes no arguments as you have it defined. You may change `import_first_excel_csv_file(df)` to `df = import_first_excel_csv_file()`

Comment: Next time try including the full traceback for the error

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
try:
    if selected_file.lower().endswith(".xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(selected_file, header=None)
        print(f"Data from '{selected_file}' imported into Dataframe:")
        print(df)
    elif selected_file.lower().endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(selected_file, header=None)
        print(f"Data from '{selected_file}' imported into Dataframe:")
        print(df)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    return df
```

You define a `try/except` block, which returns `df` when you get an exception. The problem comes when the sentence which raises the exception is where you define `df` (i.e, `pd.read_csv/excel`).

To avoid this, you could define a more detailed `except` block, separating the diferent errors you can have at that point (for example, one error if the read fails and other for the generic exceptions).